# Monitoring all AJAX requests made by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to monitor all ajax requests that have been made using JQuery on a page, and to have a callback function be called with the result of each request?

E.g I make my ajax requests:

```
$.get('foo', {foo: bar} );
$.get('bar', {bar: foo} );
```

And then I have a function called each time any of those ajax requests is completed, with the url that was referenced, and the result of the request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out jQuery's "ajaxComplete"; it should be exactly what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Using it, you can register a handler and that handler will get invoked on every ajax call.

```
$.ajaxComplete(function() {
    alert('it worked');
});

$.get('foo', {foo: bar} ); // "it worked" would get alerted when this completes
```

To see the response that came back, just use the XHR object that gets provided, like so:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr) {
    alert('it worked, and the response was:' + xhr.responseHTML);
});

$.get('foo', {foo: bar} );
```

And to check the URL you can use a third "settings" arg that gets provided:

```
$.ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    alert('it worked, and the response was:' + xhr.responseHTML);
    alert('and the original URL was:' + settings.url);
});

$.get('foo', {foo: bar} );
```

**EDIT**

As Yusuf K. helpfully pointed out in the comments, if you're using one of the new versions of jQuery such as jQuery 3, things have moved around. `ajaxComplete` is no longer a static method, but is instead an instance method that you call on `document`:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) { // ...
```

Comment: $.ajaxComplete(function().. is not worked but as mentioned in given link $( document ).ajaxComplete(function().. is worked with JQUERY 3.1.1

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you to edit answer quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Example of accessing `url` for any request using `ajaxComplete`...  taken straight from docs:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

```
$('.log').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/test.html') {
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is ' +
                     xhr.responseHTML);
  }
});
```

If you console.log() `xhr` and `settings` objects to your browser console you can see all the data you have access to within `ajaxComplete`

Answer (score 1):

You can store the requests in an array and use the chained callbacks if that's what you mean:

```
function callback( data ) {
  // do something with the request
}

var requests = [];
requests.push( $.get('foo', { foo: bar }) ); // add to array and run request
requests.push( $.get('bar', { bar: foo }) );

requests.forEach(function( request ) {
  request.done(function( data ) {
    callback( data );
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also use jQuery's deferred class (the class of the thing that comes back from an ajax call) to do that less verbosely (though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, for readability reasons) : `$.get('foo', { foo: bar }).complete(function(){$.get('bar', { foo: bar }) });`