# WooCommerce Update Cart makes number arrows disappear

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, input, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce, and on the cart page I am using custom number icons.

I found the original code here: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb

It's working on my live site here: http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/shop/cart/ (you may have to add something to the cart fist)

The problem I'm having is when I click the plus or minus then click "Update Cart" the custom number icons disappear and all that is left is the number.

My jQuery looks like:

```
$(function() {
    // Quantity
    $('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter(".quantity input");
    
    $('.quantity').each(function() {
        var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = 999999;
        
        btnUp.click(function() {
            var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
            if (oldValue >= max) {
                var newVal = oldValue;
            } else {
                var newVal = oldValue + 1;
            }
            spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
            spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
        });
        
        btnDown.click(function() {
            var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
            if (oldValue <= min) {
                var newVal = oldValue;
            } else {
                var newVal = oldValue - 1;
            }
            spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
            spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
        });
    });
});
```

My guess is the page is getting reloaded with ajax when "Update Cart" is clicked and since `insertAfter` has already been fired, it's not firing it again.

I tested something by adding:

`$('.button').click(function(){}` and appending (using `.append`) some text, thinking that when the button gets pressed the text will show. This almost works. The text shows briefly, then the page seems to refresh and the content is gone. I was thinking I might be able to use this logic to fire the original code when the submit button is clicked.

My code looks like:

Product
                Price
                Quantity
                Subtotal

```
                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <a href="http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/shop/cart/?remove_item=a1d0c6e83f027327d8461063f4ac58a6&amp;_wpnonce=c58b0e5416" class="remove" aria-label="Remove this item" data-product_id="42" data-product_sku="">×</a>                        </td>

                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                    <a href="http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/product/raw-pecan-pieces/"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/wp-content/uploads/istockphoto-1136673992-1024x1024-1-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/wp-content/uploads/istockphoto-1136673992-1024x1024-1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/wp-content/uploads/istockphoto-1136673992-1024x1024-1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/wp-content/uploads/istockphoto-1136673992-1024x1024-1-600x600.jpg 600w, http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/wp-content/uploads/istockphoto-1136673992-1024x1024-1-100x100.jpg 100w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a>                      </td>

                    <td class="product-name" data-title="Product">
                    <a href="http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/product/raw-pecan-pieces/">Raw Pecan Pieces</a>                     </td>

                    <td class="product-price" data-title="Price">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>27.56</bdi></span>                        </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
                        <div class="quantity">
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ff63bef1bbf0">Raw Pecan Pieces quantity</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5ff63bef1bbf0" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="cart[a1d0c6e83f027327d8461063f4ac58a6][qty]" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
        </div>
                        </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Subtotal">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>27.56</bdi></span>                        </td>
                </tr>
                
        
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                                        <div class="coupon">
                        <label for="coupon_code">Coupon:</label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon code"> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply coupon">Apply coupon</button>
                                                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update cart" disabled="" aria-disabled="true">Update cart</button>

                
                <input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-cart-nonce" name="woocommerce-cart-nonce" value="c58b0e5416"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/rbtest/shop/cart/">              </td>
        </tr>

                </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or shed some light on this? I feel like I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: What makes this interesting, is this doesn't happen on the product page: http://joshrodg.com/rbtest/product/raw-pecan-pieces/ ..click the plus, minus, then update and the icons are still there - so there is something specific happening on the cart page

Comment: Josh, you're right about why it's happening.  The Update Cart AJAX refresh re-writes the code that displays the form field an so your's doesn't get executed again... ...this is intriguing... I wonder if there is a way to monitor for AJAX executions on a page so you can piggyback on them?

Comment: Ok, here we go:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

What if you can check for the other AJAX to see `.when()` it fires, then simply run your `.append()` again afterwards.

Comment: This also looks promising... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025948/2757809

Comment: May be have a look to this related working thread for WooCommerce: [Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367826/custom-plus-and-minus-quantity-buttons-in-woocommerce-3/52378023#52378023)… You will need to make some little changes to get the same html and CSS output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...

The original code had to be tweaked a bit, but a friend of mine helped me get this working :-)

It was working out of the box, but when we clicked "Update Cart" it would stop, so we had to create two functions to make this work.

One for the plus and minus icons, the other for the button itself.

We wanted this to work right out of the gate, before the "Update Cart" button is clicked, so that's why we call the `qtyChange` function in the `document.ready`.

Then, we noticed that when the "Update Cart" button was clicked WooCommerce actually removes and re-adds the number input, so we have to re-execute our script after the button is clicked...but there is a catch! Since, this is done using ajax and the page actually isn't reloading, we need to wait until after the ajax process completes so that nothing executes too quickly. If I didn't put a timeout on the code, then the buttons would not show up, which was my initial problem.

I also had an issue where I got the buttons to show up, but the plus and minus icons did not make the input number advance or decrease which is what the other timeout function is for.

Finally, I had to make one more change...I added `.remove` as a selector because the X next to each product also caused the plus and minus icons to disappear.

All in all now it's working. This would've been simpler if we could have modified the WooCommerce code directly, but that could get wiped out with a plugin update so this is a better solution :-)

Now my code looks like:

```
<script>
        function qtyChange() {
            $('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter(".quantity input");
            
            $('.quantity').each(function() {
                var spinner = jQuery(this),
                input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
                btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
                btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
                min = input.attr('min'),
                max = 999999;
                
                btnUp.click(function() {
                    var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
                    if (oldValue >= max) {
                        var newVal = oldValue;
                    } else {
                        var newVal = oldValue + 1;
                    }
                    spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
                    spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
                });
                
                btnDown.click(function() {
                    var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
                    if (oldValue <= min) {
                        var newVal = oldValue;
                    } else {
                        var newVal = oldValue - 1;
                    }
                    spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
                    spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
                });
            });

        }

        function cartUpdate() {
            $('button[name="update_cart"], .remove').click(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    qtyChange();
                }, 3000);
                
                setTimeout(function(){
                    cartUpdate();
                }, 3000);
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            qtyChange();
            cartUpdate();
        });
    </script>
```

*The 3000 timeout seems a bit high, but every lower number I tried still produced various issues where something wasn't working. Everything executes with that timeout all the time, which is the goal :-) Just have to put up with a little delay and everything works!